# Let my Application be controlled by GPOs

Tags: c#, .net, group-policy, gpo

I am developing a windows application. I want my application to be configurable via own-defined GPOs, that the system administrator can manage my application behaviour for each group and user individually.
I've done some research, but I just could not find a proper solution.

If I create some custom policies, how do they get on the server?
I think the policies should consist of "changing registry entries". After that, my application uses these entries on the local machine to configure itselft.

For example my application has a Folder in which data is getting stored. Let's say it is "C:\data" by default. This path is stored in a specific registry entry. By defining a group policy, the administrator can change this path. So the administrator sets the path to "C:\subfolder\data" on the server side. My local application should now use this folder to store the data.

I could not figure out how to solve this. is there a way to get the group policies onto the server/domain controller?
I'd like to publish my application later, so I definitely prefer a solution using something like an installer package.

Comment: This really sounds like it should be an installer-based variable instead of a GPO. To get a GPO to work you first have to install it to the domain and then push out the GPO to all machines before you can actually use it. Also, as a sysadmin I would assume that changing the GPO would affect all existing installations, too, would it? One other thing, since this policy is registry that means that everyone will have `HKLM\Software\YourApp` regardless of whether they have it installed. I'd personally prefer to just have a command line override switch or even an INF settings file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "I think the policies should consist of "changing registry entries". After that, my application uses these entries on the local machine to configure itself."

Yes that is the best way to do it. Create registry configuration under `HKLM\Software\YourAppNameHere` or `HKCU\Software\YourAppNameHere` (depending on whether you want per-user or per-machine config).

Your application should just read the registry entry and not worry about group policies.

You can then create ADM or ADMX files which you can install on the domain controller, or simply document the registry entries and let administrators create their own group policies or deploy the registry key in another way.

**Edit:** A good example of creating an ADM or ADMX file which just deploys registry keys is found in this Microsoft KB article:

- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/918238